# Magento over SSL, Varnish?

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl, varnish

I run my Magento shop on a CentOS 7 Apache server and all pages are load over https.
This because of the SEO-score and safety.

But is it useful to install and config Varnish on this server, because I load all pages over https?

Comment: you can use nginx -> varnish <- nginx to create some sort of "roundabout" to server encrypted/non-ecrypted content. but sometimes it creates more headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish can't terminate SSL connections, so you'll need to use something else (such as pound or nginx) in front of Varnish to accomplish this.

If you use Turpentine, we have [some limited information](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/SSL_Support). There also issues/discussion of how others have accomplished this. It's complicated and you'll likely need some help from your hosting provider to get it all set up and working.